# How can I return all the values from my array inside a function?

Tags: php

```
function my($array){
while($pointer = current($array)){
    return $pointer;
    next($array);
}
}
$myArray =[1,2,3];
$showValues = my($myArray);
echo $showValues;
//I only get the first element back
//When I use echo it works fine
```

Comment: Which language is that? Please add a tag for the language.

Comment: I'm sure it's because I can only return one value with return;I tried adding brackets to $pointer and got Array as my return value.

Comment: Thanks for the tag.

Comment: can you specify what the function needs to return? for example, I passed [1,2,3] to the function, and it must return ..... something for this particular case ... ? just didn't understand the question, I pass the array to the function and it will need to return the same array, what's the point?

Comment: I'm trying to figure out how to return multiple values with return.

Comment: just `function my($array) {return $array;}` or you can do something and return like this: `return ['hello'=>'world', 'arg'=>$array]` , and use `print_r` or `var_dump` an array instead of echo. `print_r($showValus)` or `var_dump($showValues)`

Comment: What is your desire output?

Comment: You will get only first value. The code after your-> return $pointer will never execute. If you want multiple values push your $pointer is an array and return that array after your while statement.

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
array array_values ( array $myArray)
```

[array_values()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-values.php) returns all the values from the array and indexes the array numerically

Answer (score 0):

You have a couple options, the standard way is to just return an array instead of a single value, and another is to create a new array by [passing by reference](http://php.net/manual/en/language.references.pass.php), so technically you do not return anything, but the result is similar *(an array)*:

```
// Return an array
function my($array)
    {
        foreach($array as $key => $value)
            $row[$key]  =   $value;

        return $row;
    }

// Pass by reference
function myPass($array,&$new)
    {
        foreach($array as $key => $value)
            $new[$key]  =   $value;
    }
```

**Return an array:**

```
$myArray    =   array(1,2,3);
$notRef     =   my($myArray);
print_r($notRef);
```

**Pass by reference:**

```
$myArray    =   array(1,2,3);
$new        =   array();
myPass($myArray,$new);
print_r($new);
```

**Gives you (both ways):**

```
Array
(
    [0] => 1
    [1] => 2
    [2] => 3
)
```